# Java thread dump without jstack

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, shell, monitoring

I need to monitor java thread status from command line(ubuntu server) to use with Icinga monitor. But i cannot use jps, jstack and jcmd commands since it's not allowed to have JDK installed in production server.

The process_id with ps command

```
# ps -ef| grep [s]tart.jar | cut -d' ' -f6
1201
```

But I am struggling to collect java thread dump. I have tried with kill -3  but couldn't get any output.

Is there any other alternative ways to collect java thread status from command line ?

Comment: "but couldn't get any output" why? There is no output? Output is redirected to file you have no access?

Comment: @talex, thanks for asking. Your question made to think of output location and I have written in answer section. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the way to capture thread dump when executing `kill -3 <pid>`.
I have added following options to JAVA_OPTIONS in jetty server which helps to records thread dump in specified location.

```
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+LogVMOutput -XX:LogFile=/var/log/jetty9/threaddump.log
```

Now execution of `kill -3 <pid>` command records thread dump in threaddump.log which is used to know status of threads.